# call an event in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I call an event this way:

```
event(new NewsLetterActivation($user));
```

**and in event:**

```
public $user;
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

It works.

Now In sometimes, I have an extra string variable and also may I did not have
an $user ($user is empty or null).

How can I call it?

I try this:

```
event(new NewsLetterActivation(null,'a@a.com'));
```

and in event:

```
public function __construct(User $user,$email=null)
{
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->email= $email;
}
```

error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Events\NewsLetterActivation::__construct() must be an instance of App\Events\User, null given
```

Comment: It's saying you *have* to pass in a user, you can't pass in null. You may be able to assign it to null, but I'm not sure if you have to take out the `User` declaration or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Since PHP 7.1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php) you can do this to be able to pass `null`:

```
public function __construct(?User $user)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your controller to the following-

```
public function __construct($user,$email=null)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->email= $email;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `__construct()` method or Listener you must change input parameter:

```
public function __construct(array $arg)
{
    if (isset($agr['user])) {
        $this->user = $agr['user];
    }
    if (isset($arg['email'])) {
        $this->email= $agr['email'];
    }
}
```

Then you can call event by different ways:

```
event(new NewsLetterActivation(['email'=>'a@a.com']);
event(new NewsLetterActivation(['email'=>'a@a.com', 'user'=>$user]);
event(new NewsLetterActivation(['user'=>$user]);
event(new NewsLetterActivation([]);
```